# How to structure data in order to import it to the Firestore emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore

Here is a piece of the Firebase emulators doc, that says that you can import data to your Firestore emulator by doing:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./dir
```

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkgvFNPdiEs) from the Firebase channel also talks a little about this.

But none of those sources mention how you should structure your data in order to import it to Firestore.

I think they assume you are importing something that you've previously exported from the Firestore emulator.

But what about when you are starting off your project and you need to feed brand new data to the Firestore emulator? Data to multiple collections.

How should that be done? What format should the data be in?

**NOTE:** Don't know if it matters, but I'm using the firebase JS client for the web.

[image]